# ASUS ROG STRIX GL553VE won't wake up from sleep

Tags: windows-10, laptop, asus-laptop, laptop-repair

My ASUS ROG STRIX GL553VE after a long time with a closed lid won't wake up properly from sleep.

The keyboard light is on, but the screen is still black.

OS - Windows 10 Pro.

By the way - if I close for a few mins the lid and then open it - everything is working fine.

What can be a reason of this and how to fix this issue ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From past experience it's a hibernate issue I've seen it with every windows version so far, go to control panel then power settings, then either choose when to turn off display or sleep option from there go to advanced settings, then choose the sleep dropdown and change hibernate to never, that should fix the issue,you can also change hard drive to never power down

Comment: It doesn't help  - right now I have the same situation. Looks like HDD and screen are not woken up..